# Compact drainage rock behind retaining wall?

Tags: retaining-wall, backyard

I am confused by the mfg instructions and its images. It states to fill core and 12 inches back with drainage crushed rock, and to compact, "backfill"

First, what type of rick can i use for drainage and core fill? Will clean crushed limestone work? I also have about 1.5 tons of river rock. Can the two be mixed?

Second, should the drainage rock be compacted? Looking at the picture in the instructions it almost looks like 
That's what is happening.

Based off my image of my current site do i need to use any special back fill and compact it behind the wall? I planned to fill with drain rock and then top off with dirt but I am confused now.

Can the base be hand tamped or is a plate compactor a must?

These are beveled denver retaining wall blocks at H:6in W:17inch and depth 12 inches.  I planned to do less than 36 inches at highest area.

Mfg instructions:
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

My site work in progress base dig:
[image]